# String binary search in Java

Tags: java, binary-search

I am learning using binary search in Java. In an integer list it returns expected index but in char or a String list (code example) it returns a negative index, which is not expected (index = -4).

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
str.add("Hey");
str.add("Hi");
str.add("Bye");
int index = Collections.binarySearch(str,"Hi");
System.out.println(index);
```

Answer (score 3):

The pre-condition of a binary search is: the underlying data must be **sorted**.

So, **sort** that list first.

And then you want to check that the index returned by that method is between 0 and the size() of your list. It is a bit naive to expect that **any** string could be found in your list and return a non-zero index.

Beyond that; the **real** answer here: don't just blindly use a built-in functionality. Read its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)) **first** to understand what this method is doing, and for example: what values it will return to you!

Answer (score 2):

Your `List` must be sorted in order for binary search to work.
The natural ordering of `String`s is lexicographical order, so `"Bye"` should come before `"Hey"` and `"Hi"`.

Try

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
str.add("Bye");
str.add("Hey");
str.add("Hi");

int index = Collections.binarySearch(str,"Hi");
System.out.println(index);
```

Comment: Or, for a more dynamic approach (i.e. not having to manually order them but let Java do it), `Collections#sort`.